# How can I open a New Ubuntu 20.04 shell (WSL2) in VSCode integrated terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, wsl-2

On my machine I have installed the WSL2 on Windows 10 Pro and a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS distro. I am also using VSCode as editor for programming. I start VSCode in Windows (not in the WSL2 Ubuntu) and there is the possibility to create a new terminal using the profile "New Ubuntu-20.04 (Standard) (WSL)".

[Image: Start New Ubuntu 20.04 (Standard) (WSL)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxRZk.jpg)
[image]

However, this doesn't work as it calls the command "wsl -d Ubuntu-20.04 (Standard)" thus interpreting "(Standard)" as a command to be executed in WSL. This obviously fails as there is no command "(Standard)".

[Image: Error message starting the shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqfHd.jpg)
[image]

How can I change this profile? Is that possible at all?

As a workaround I can create a new profile in my VSCode user settings and pass the correct argument to the "wsl" command. But then I still have the defective profile entry in the integrated terminal. But I just want to have working entries there.

thanks in advance

Lars

Comment: You can rename your profile in the settings.json file   (`"C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\settings.json"` )  (or `CTRL+,` inside [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal))

Comment: @Luuk, it seems, you are referring to a settings.json that is used by the Windows Terminal App (which I also have installed apparently). But it didn't do the trick, since I have a problem with the Terminal _integrated in VSCode. Maybe, there is a similar config file for that....

Comment: Hmmm, Microsoft seems to have decided to give "Visual Code" its own setting for starting a Terminal session 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The April 2021 release of VS code fixed the issue.

Comment: Have checked it - indeed. This works now. I like :)